# Issue With Json Parsing

Tags: apex, json

I am trying to parse this json response :

```
[{
    "statut1": true,
    "json1": {
        "titre": "Impôt 2018 sur les revenus de l'année 2017",
        "declarant1": {
            "nom": "C***",
            "nomDeNaissance": "C***",
            "prenom": "EM**",
            "dateDeNaissance": "08/08/1996"
        },
        "declarant2": {
            "nom": "",
            "nomDeNaissance": "",
            "prenom": "",
            "dateDeNaissance": ""
        },
        "adresse": "1*****L",
        "dateMiseEnRecouvrementAvisImpot": "31/07/2018",
        "dateEtablissement": "10/07/2018",
        "nombreParts": "1.00",
        "situationDefamille": "Célibataire",
        "nombreDePersonnesCharge": "0",
        "revenuBrutGlobal": "10650 €",
        "revenuImposable": "10650 €",
        "impotSurRevenueNetAvantCorrections": "Non imposable",
        "montantImpot": "Non imposable",
        "revenuFiscalReference": "10650 €"
    }
}, {
    "statut2": true,
    "json2": {
        "titre": "Impôt 2018 sur les revenus de l'année 2017",
        "declarant1": {
            "nom": "B***",
            "nomDeNaissance": "B***",
            "prenom": "A***",
            "dateDeNaissance": "13/10/1991"
        },
        "declarant2": {
            "nom": "",
            "nomDeNaissance": "",
            "prenom": "",
            "dateDeNaissance": ""
        },
        "adresse": "13 ***",
        "dateMiseEnRecouvrementAvisImpot": "31/07/2018",
        "dateEtablissement": "10/07/2018",
        "nombreParts": "1.00",
        "situationDefamille": "Célibataire",
        "nombreDePersonnesCharge": "0",
        "revenuBrutGlobal": "14559 €",
        "revenuImposable": "14559 €",
        "impotSurRevenueNetAvantCorrections": "Non imposable",
        "montantImpot": "Non imposable",
        "revenuFiscalReference": "14559 €"
    }
} ,{
    "statut3": true,
    "json3": {
        "titre": "Impôt 2018 sur les revenus de l'année 2017",
        "declarant1": {
            "nom": "**",
            "nomDeNaissance": "***",
            "prenom": "***",
            "dateDeNaissance": "08/08/1996"
        },
        "declarant2": {
            "nom": "",
            "nomDeNaissance": "",
            "prenom": "",
            "dateDeNaissance": ""
        },
        "adresse": "13******",
        "dateMiseEnRecouvrementAvisImpot": "31/07/2018",
        "dateEtablissement": "10/07/2018",
        "nombreParts": "1.00",
        "situationDefamille": "Célibataire",
        "nombreDePersonnesCharge": "0",
        "revenuBrutGlobal": "10650 €",
        "revenuImposable": "10650 €",
        "impotSurRevenueNetAvantCorrections": "Non imposable",
        "montantImpot": "Non imposable",
        "revenuFiscalReference": "10650 €"
    }
}
```

]
I tried this :

List results=(List)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                System.debug('le resultat du json  '+results);
                System.debug('taille du json  '+results.size());

```
            Map<String, Object> infoclient = (Map<String, Object>)((results)[0]);
            System.debug('json1     '+infoclient);
```

i get this error:System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Map to List

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99399/discussion-on-question-by-maya-issue-with-json-parsing).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. I don't see any problem with that.

You succeeded to parse the JSON response and to put it into a map. What you see in the System.debug is the display of the Map (it will not display all the map).

You can verify with another way:

```
Map<String, Object> results =(Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());      
System.debug('le resultat du json pour status1 :  ' + results.get('statut1'));
System.debug('le resultat du json pour status3 :  ' + results.get('statut2'));
```

You will have as an output :

```
le resultat du json pour status1 : true
le resultat du json pour status3 : true
```

Comment: Amer, this can only work if the JSON is correctly formatted.

Comment: Exactly Chris .. Anyway I assumed that she received the JSON from an External API call (response.getBody()) and that the example she posted is just many response example.

Comment: @AmerNassereldine I changed the format of the json and i get this error Invalid conversion from runtime type Map to List

Comment: @ChrisJohnson i changed the JSON format

Answer (score 0):

This JSON consists of List of elements. So we need to convert the deserializeUntyped JSON to List of objects. See the below code for your reference.

```
    List<Object> results = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
```